# Append Multi-Dimension Arrays Horizontally in Blocks

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have several Multi-Dimension Arrays, that I wish to concatenate horizontally. Thinking of the Multi-Dimension Arrays as tables, I want to append each by stacking them horizontally.

I have tried to use map and nested map, but I cannot get it work exactly as described.

```
var arr1 = [["A1","B1","C1","D1"],["A2","B2","C2","D2"]]
var arr2 = [["E1","F1","G1","H1"],["E2","F2","G2","H2"]]
```

how can I merge these into a single array where the output would be

```
var arrMerged = [["A1","B1","C1","D1","E1","F1","G1","H1"],["A2","B2","C2","D2","E2","F2","G2","H2"]]
```

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: You should try to ready [this](https://howchoo.com/g/mzbmyzi2zda/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: You say that you've tried `map`. Add that code to your question so we can assess it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version with `map`.

```js
const arr1 = [["A1","B1","C1","D1"],["A2","B2","C2","D2"]]
const arr2 = [["E1","F1","G1","H1"],["E2","F2","G2","H2"]];

const out = arr1.map((arr, i) => {
  return arr.concat(arr2[i]);
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.push and spread syntax to achieve your solution.

```js
var arr1 = [["A1","B1","C1","D1"],["A2","B2","C2","D2"]]
var arr2 = [["E1","F1","G1","H1"],["E2","F2","G2","H2"]]
const output = []
// if you know the maximum length you can provide yourself instead of Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)
for(let i =0; i < Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++){
    //This will work even with different lengths of array
 output.push([...(arr1[i] || []), ...(arr2[i] || [])])
}
console.log(output)
```

P.S.: You can use other methods like map and reduce, but i am using for loop because in case of map the length of all arrays should be same.